# Application error: Service Unavailable on Einstein Analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics, data-set, dataflow

When I try to create a dataset in one of our sandboxes I get this error.
Also when I try to add the APIEvent object, I'm not getting the fields list to select from. What am I missing?

This works in a different sandbox. I tried to push a changeset from the dev sandbox to this full sandbox but that throws errors as well. I have added these permission sets as well

Einstein Analytics Platform Admin
Event Monitoring Analytics Admin[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this error occur if the Right key is empty on an augment node.

If you have augments in the dataflow, open each node and verify that you have a right key.

This error will also occur if the Fields to keep or drop in a slice node is left empty.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I also see UserId and Derived User Id. But the key is set for Derived User Id, not sure if that's empty and causing the issue.